# Router disconnecting ssh sessions after approx. 5 minutes

Tags: router, wide-area-network

If have a draytek 2820 series router that continues to disconnect my ssh sessions after approx. 5 minutes. I suspect it disconnects other stuff as well, because users have been complaining about having to send large emails twice, after receiving errors.

I tried altering the MTU and other stuff to no avail. The router is behind a DOCSYS modem, can this have something to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

Your ssh problem sounds like a problem with an idle connection; I don't think it's the MTU, as that would cause other strange problems.

Comment: probably yes, but are there any generic settings for routers or DOCSYS modems that affect idle connections? I could not find them.

Comment: It is easiest enough to test if it is the idle timer -- simply sit there for 5 minutes hitting the space bar every couple of seconds.  If you still get disconnected its no the idle timer.